# WordPress: Javascript function called when widget is added

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is a question about core WordPress code relating to the **Customizer** that is part of the **WordPress Admin**.

Using Wordpress (as of writing, v4.9.x) a widget may be added to the site like this:

1. Log in and view the site
2. Click on "Customizer" in the admin bar
3. Go to "Widgets" and then the Widget area
4. Click on [+Add a Widget]
5. Click on a widget from the available widgets list
6. Widget appears in the customizer

My question is: what is the javascript code that is executed in step (5) when the available widget is clicked, and in which file can I find it?

The code I am trying to find (which is part of core Wordpress) appears to iterate over every single widget instance in the site, including those NOT in the current sidebar. This slows down my site which has many (1000+) widget instances. I would like to find where this iteration happens.

The image attached is of a typical case when [+Add a Widget] is clicked and shows the iteration over the widget instances. The image is of a site that has only several 10's of widget instances. The site I'm trying to improve has over 1000 so is taking ~45 seconds to execute this javascript.

**Some background that may help:** The site has maybe 200 pages, each with it's own widget area. Widgets are added to each page individually. Widgets are used to build the page content. That is why there are so many widgets.

Please, no answers regarding the abuse of WP widgets functionality. I know they are being used in a non-standard way.

[image]

Comment: By default, widget does not use javascript, this must be special implementation related to your theme or the plugins you are using. Widget are [registered via hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget), if there is any javascript is using, it is probably within the customised widget class that extend from `WP_widget`, check your theme `function.php` or plugins for the definition of those special widget classes. Those classes probably register the javascript via `wp_register_script` within its construct or methods.

Comment: @hcheung This is not correct. We are talking about the Customizer in the WordPress admin. We are not talking about the implementation of widgets. wp-admin/js contains several widget related javascript files that are part of the default WordPress install. These include `customize-widgets.js` and `widgets.js`. Likewise, wp-includes/js contains widget related javascript files in a default wordpress install.

Comment: So the site you're trying to improve has over 1000 unique widget types? Not the text widget used 1000 times...

Comment: @disinfor I'll update my description - it has only a few unique widget types, but has 1000 instances of them. The site has maybe 200 pages. Each page with it's own widget area (sidebar). Widgets are used to build the content for each page.